# Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an x_test data:

```
x_test.shape
Out[11]: (13096, 30)

x_test.size
Out[16]: 392880
```

When I launch the prediction it return an error:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (13096, 30)

My code is very simple, I'm trying to run the predict function:

```
test_df= pd.read_csv("Path_data")
model = load_model.("path_model")
Xnew = np.array(test_df)

# make a prediction

predictions = model.predict_classes(Xnew)
```

Model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 50, 100)           50400     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 50, 100)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 50)                30200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 80,651
Trainable params: 80,651
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Someone please can tell me how can I resolve this issue ?
Thank you

Comment: You should take a look at the doc, LSTM networks expect your dataset to have a very specific shape: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/

Comment: Can you print the model summary and put it here ?

Comment: @SkanderHR I just edited my question, adding model summary.

Comment: @SkanderHR BTW I changed the array to a 3D. Then I got this error: 
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (50, 25) but got array with shape (13096, 30)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable x_test should have the input dimensions required by the LSTM layer which is a 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]

Answer (score 1):

This is dimension mismatch, the model expect to have a data record itself as an array of arrays, ie, if you have an image i, it expects, `np.array([i])`, Try :

```
x_train = np.array([ [i] for i in x_train])
```

This will increment the dimension by 1